# macos - Command source fix a php but broke other paths?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I want to have a `php` permissions on my terminal, but right now, if I type:

`php -v` as a result I got: `zsh: command not found: php`, interesting is next.

Without the next command I have a flutter path, for example, to run `flutter doctor`, but if I run command `source ~/.bash_profile` as a result I got a version of PHP, and everything it’s ok, but my path for flutter (as an example) is broken.

```
PHP 7.4.26 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2021 01:21:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

...

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

When I reset my PC, must run the `source ~/.bash_profile` command to be able to use PHP.

Comment: You are using zsh. Show the content of `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

**From your description**, the **probable cause** of your issue **might** be associated with setting path in your shell. Your `$PATH` in `ZSH` might be overwritten (not appended) during the `source ~/.bash_profile`, hence making the `php` available and not the `flutter`.

Make sure PATH is set correctly in `ZSH` and `BASH` using the below format.

```
export PATH=$PATH:"your_directory"
```

or

```
export PATH="your_directory":$PATH
```

If `$PATH` is not present, then this is causing your issue. Verify this in your `.bash_profile`.

As pointed out in comment by **OstoneO**, the content of `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bash_profile` will be relevant to pinpoint the issue.